# Joomla 2.5 custom component PDF/Excel export

Tags: excel, pdf, joomla, export

I created a custom component for Joomla 2.5.
I have some views where the user selects several options and the system returns tables with data according to the parameters selection.
My problem is that I'd like to export these tables in PDF/Excel format without having to reload the page. I would also like to export only tha data returned from the model and not any other element of the page.

One solution might be to create a new view that creates the pdf or the excel and load it for example into a hidden iframe (am I stupid?)

My problem is that I would like to have something resusable...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a link on your site to download the excel like

index.php?option=com_myawesomecomponent&task=pdf.download&catid=10

Your controller action can then set the correct headers as nicholas did on his akeeba release system to force the browser to download the data

https://github.com/akeeba/release-system/blob/development/component/frontend/models/downloads.php#L213